# Localhost alias not working on XAMPP

Tags: macos, apache, xampp, localhost, alias

I've installed XAMPP in Mountain Lion and I'm trying to get mysite.local aliased to localhost/~user/mysite.

In /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/user/Sites/mysite"
    ServerName mysite.local
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

and in /etc/hosts I have:

`127.0.0.1        localhost mysite.local`

When I go to http://mysite.local it only shows me the XAMPP start page.

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Is this is the first time you are doing this then first of all make sure that `httpd-vhosts.conf` is being included in your general `httpd.conf` (or `apache.conf`) file.

Normally these are included in the `httpd.conf` file but commented out, just remove the comment.

Also make sure you have restarted apache after making these changes.

Comment: No Joy. I uncommented `Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and also tried `Include /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` but I'm still getting the XAMPP splash page.

Comment: Sounds like you are maybe editing the wrong httpd.conf file, XAMPP uses its own stuff, usually found within /Applications/XAMPP/etc/ (from memory)